# Am I spawning more threads then I think I am in my mapper?

Tags: java, hadoop, emr

I'm attempting to make a web parser using and since by nature there is downtime while the program retrieves the document from I made it multithreaded.  The idea being that my Threads retrieve the URLS from a url pile.  This tripled the speed of the program when I ran it on EMR with medium instances.  On large instances I got out of memory errors.  Do I just need less threads or is the number of threads less strictly controlled then I think it is?  Here is my mapper:

```
public static class Map extends MapReduceBase implements Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, Text> {
        private Text word = new Text();
        private URLPile pile= new URLPile();

        @Override
        public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, OutputCollector<Text, Text> output, Reporter reporter)  {

            // non english encoding list, all others are considered english to
            // avoid missing any
            String url = value.toString();
            StringTokenizer urls = new StringTokenizer(url);
            Config.LoggerProvider = LoggerProvider.DISABLED;
            MyThread[] Threads = new MyThread[8];
            for(MyThread thread : Threads){
                thread = new MyThread(output,pile);
                thread.start();
            }

                while (urls.hasMoreTokens()) {
                    try{

                        if(urls.hasMoreTokens()){
                            word.set(urls.nextToken());
                            String currenturl= word.toString();   
                             pile.addUrl(currenturl);
                        }else{
                            System.out.println("out of tokens");
                            pile.waitTillDone();
                        }


                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        /*

                         */
                        continue;
                    }


                }


        }

}
```

Comment: Your URLPile class - does it cache the output (in memory) until everything has completed - can it be amended to output as each URL completes?

Comment: It actually does do that, I found out the issue was that map is called once for each output and that it resulted in a bunch of empty threads being created.  I'm now attempting this with the multithreaded mapper class.